# Mapping one list to another (in Haskell, + abstract solution) - 'map reduce'?

Tags: function, haskell

Say we have a list of coordinates like:
    (1,2)
    (0,3)
    (4,1)
    (0,3)
    (-2,3)
    (6,5)

And we wanted to result in the following list, which is defined as the summation of each consecutive coordinates. (Sorry bad definition) like so:
    (1,5)
    (4,4)
    (4,4)
    (-2,6)
    (4,8)

So there exists a set A = (a,b,c,...,n) where a,b,c,...,n are coordinates in R^2.
There exists a function f such that f(A) = B = (a+b,b+c,c+d,...,n-1+n).

~

How would you write something like that in a functional language like Haskell? A program that applies f to a given A to give B.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `zip` to zip the list with its tail, you get pairs of pairs like `[((1,2), (0,3)), ((0,3),(4,1)), ...]`. Then you can use `map` to replace each pair of pairs with its sum. Or you can use `zipWith` which is basically `zip` + `map` in one function, except the function given to `zipWith` has type `a -> b -> c`, not `(a,b) -> c`:

```
summedCoords = zipWith (\ (a,b) (c,d) -> (a+c, b+d)) coords (tail coords)
```

Comment: I think you meant `summedCoords coords = zipWith (\ (a,b) (c,d) -> (a+c, b+d)) coords (tail coords)`? :)

Comment: @Shin: Yes, I absolutely did. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a generic function like this

```
g:: (a -> a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
g f (x1:x2:xs) = (f x1 x2):(g (x2:xs))
g _ (x1:[]) = []
```

and pass it your add function

```
f = g f' where 
    f' (a,b) (a',b') = (a+a', b+b')
```